# $E(X)*E(X'X)^{-1}$ simplifies when X vector contains a constant?

Tags: expected-value, matrix-inverse

For self study, I've calculated $E(X)*E(X'X)^{-1}=[1,0]$ when $X=[1,X_2]$ for any scalar random variable $X_2$ (with finite mean and variance).

Proof:
$\begin{pmatrix}1 & E(X_2)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & E(X_2) \\ E(X_2) & E(X^2_2)
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & E(X_2)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} E(X^2_2)/Var(X_2) & -E(X_2)/Var(X_2) \\ -E(X_2)/Var(X_2) & 1/Var(X_2)
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Simulations show this should work for higher dimensions (i.e. $X_2$ as a vector). I cannot figure out how to generalize the proof as calculating the inverse for more than a 3x3 is very difficult. Any help would be appreciated.